# I am making a gamified app for people with diabetes without a CGM (Continuous Glucose Monitor) and I am struggling with the score

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want the stored score to be +10 when the `bloodSugarsToday` is 6 or more and today passes and -10 when the `bloodSugarsToday` is less than 6 and today passes.

Currently I am stuck between 10 and -10, not more, not less. I've  tried to keep the score as 0 if less than 6 and 20 if equal or more tomorrow, and 10 if less than 6 and 30 if equal or more the next day and the same thing backwards but I am suck with 10 and -10

Here is the project link: https://kyletabone-diabetesgame.netlify.app/login

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="logo" src="../assets/Logo.svg" id="logo">
    <HelloWorld msg="Keep logging to earn these rewards"/>
    Score: {{ score }}<br>
    Logged {{ bloodSugarsToday.length }} times today <br>
    Logged {{ bloodSugars.length }} times total
    <div class="card-row">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="../assets/lock-icon.svg" v-if="locked" class="lock-icon" alt="Lock Icon">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <img src="../assets/BloodMedals/Bronze.svg" alt="Placeholder image">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="content">
            Get 50 points to unlock this reward
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="../assets/lock-icon.svg" v-if="locked" class="lock-icon" alt="Lock Icon">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <img src="../assets/BloodMedals/Silver.svg" alt="Placeholder image">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="content">
            Get 100 points to unlock this reward
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="../assets/lock-icon.svg" v-if="locked" class="lock-icon" alt="Lock Icon">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <img src="../assets/BloodMedals/Gold.svg" alt="Placeholder image">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="content">
            Get 150 points to unlock this reward
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  orderBy,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "@/firebase/index";

export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      locked: true,
      score: 0,
      bloodSugars: [],
      bloodSugarsToday: [],
      averageGlucose: 0,
      lastScoreUpdateDate: null,
      isScoreUpdated: false,
      isScoreUpdatedToday: false,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    const today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Set the time to midnight
    this.showLocked();

    const updateBloodSugars = (snapshot) => {
  const fbBloodSugars = [];
  const fbBloodSugarsToday = [];
  let fbBloodSugarsTodayCounter = 1; // Counter for fbBloodSugarsToday IDs

  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const bloodSugar = {
      id: doc.id,
      value: Number(doc.data().value),
      date: new Date(doc.data().date),
      time: doc.data().time,
    };
    fbBloodSugars.push(bloodSugar);

    const today = new Date(); // Get current date
    if (
      bloodSugar.date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
      bloodSugar.date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
      bloodSugar.date.getDate() === today.getDate()
    ) {
      const bloodSugarToday = { ...bloodSugar, id: fbBloodSugarsTodayCounter };
      fbBloodSugarsToday.push(bloodSugarToday);
      fbBloodSugarsTodayCounter++;
    }
  });

  console.log(fbBloodSugarsToday.length);
  if (fbBloodSugarsToday.length >= 6) {
    this.score += 10;
  } else {
    this.score -= 10;
  }

  this.storeScore(); // Call the storeScore() function to store the score

  this.bloodSugars = fbBloodSugars;
  this.bloodSugarsToday = fbBloodSugarsToday;

  this.retrieveScore(); // Call the retrieveScore() function to retrieve the score
};


    onSnapshot(
      query(collection(db, 'BloodSugars'), orderBy('date', 'desc')),
      updateBloodSugars
    );
  },

  methods: {
    showLocked() {
      if (this.locked) {
        const cardImages = document.getElementsByClassName("card-image");
        for (let i = 0; i < cardImages.length; i++) {
          cardImages[i].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        }
      }
    },

    resetScore() {
      this.score = 0;
      this.storeScore(); // Store the updated score
    },

    retrieveScore() {
      // Retrieve the score from localStorage
      const storedScore = localStorage.getItem('score');
      if (storedScore) {
        this.score = parseInt(storedScore, 10);
      }
    },

    storeScore() {
      // Store the score in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('score', this.score.toString());
    },
  },
};
</script>
```